# Ubuntu freezes when gdm starts

Tags: boot, xorg, gdm, startup, freeze

I have Ubuntu 10.10 (upgraded from 10.04)
I was browsing in Firefox yesterday, then the PC suddenly did a reset

Once it restarted, everything went normal until gdm begun showing. Then everything froze and locked when userlist showed. **I can't move mouse pointer nor do anything with keyboard at this point (just after userlist shows in gdm)**.

PS: Both, mouse and keyboard work fine, because this Ubuntu is dual-booting with a Windows XP install which loads/works fine.

**Here is my .xsession-errors file, but I don't have a clue what may be wrong. Thanks**

http://pastebin.com/GVtneEAF

Comment: The problem/bug is likely in xorg. Please post links to your xorg.log and xorg.0.log (both files are in /var/log).

Comment: I don't have xorg.log ... I only have these: http://i.imgur.com/zsNbp.jpg and here I've posted xorg.0.log file details http://pastebin.com/yw4x0ArX Thanks

Comment: Same problem with kernel 2.6.38-4-generic on natty. All was working fine before this upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Similar things started happening to me after I upgraded to the 2.6.35-25 kernel.  That may not be the cause of your problem, but try when you boot selecting the previous kernel version instead (2.6.35-24) and see if the problems go away.

Here's a related bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/703553

Comment: Hi edtechdev. I've tried booting with previous kernels from my grub menu, but doesn't help at all

Comment: These are my entries in grub. 2.6.36-020636-generic, (same with recovery mode), 2.6.35-23-generic, (same with recovery mode), 2.6.35-22-generic, (same with recovery mode), memory test, and Windows XP... none of ubuntu entries in grub work

Comment: My problems (from that kernel upgrade as well) needed a power off and battery remove to reset the graphics card to a stable state. After that, try booting your previous kernel.